# Angular library: configure exported members

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

How can I define the exported members of my Angular library? I am using the `public-api.ts` file, containing:

```
export * from './lib/my-lib.module';
```

But when importing the library to a module, the editor (Webstorm) still suggests importing other classes included in the library, but just belonging internals.

```
imports: [
          MyLib...
              > MyLibModule
              > MyLibComponent
              > MyLibService
```

How can they be hidden? There should only stay `MyLibModule` as defined in the `public-api.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try export module in `public-api.ts` with this way:

```
export { MyLibModule as MyLibModule } from "./lib/my-lib.module";
```

Optionally created the `index.ts` file and export:

```
export * from "./public-api.ts";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, as the editor still searches in the subfolders for importable classes.